# Fastest way to get has_many association records in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many through association where I have many products which have different prices depending on countries (they can only have one price per country).

The loop I'm trying to do is the following

```rb
@product.countries.each do |country|
  country.name 
  # here I want to get the price of this product in that country
end
```

I want something which does something similiar to `country.prices.where(product_id: @product.id).first`

I'm sure there is a clean way to right this code without having to use a where. Any idea on how to do this ?

---

Here is are my models

**products**

```
has_many :prices
has_many :countries, through :prices
```

**prices**

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :country
belongs_to :currency
```

**countries**

```
has_many :prices
has_many :products, through :prices
```

Comment: You can preload the data. Here is how to do it: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flip this around and process them like this:

```rb
@product.prices.each do |price|
  price.country.name
  # now you already have the price
end
```

Of course, your countries will now potentially be in an unsatisfactory order, and for each price that you display you'll be triggering an additional DB query. With a large table of prices this could quickly become a performance issue.

The solution would be to either create a scope that you can use, or manually fetch your prices rather than just using the bare association, allowing you to eager-load your associated data and order your prices based on them:

```rb
# In your controller, or model code somewhere:
@prices = @product.prices.joins(:country).order('countries.name').includes(:country)
# The joins is required for ordering, and the includes ensures you eager-load that data

# In your view:
@prices.each do |price|
  price.country.name # Now these should be in the correct order and eager-loaded rather than fetched in ever iteration of this prices loop
  # you already have the price to use here
end
```